# Laravel 5.3 API route not saving session between requests

Tags: laravel, jwt

I am trying to build a static HTML viewer through Laravel's 5.3 API routing logic and JWT. The files are all stored on S3 and need to be protected so I thought the best way to do this was to make a kind of proxy that all the files pass through. That way I can check the token of the user from the API request and load the files accordingly.

The first file loads fine.

```
http://example.com/api/proxy/file.html?token={token}
```

The issue arises when the HTML file tries to load files from itself. It works when I strip out the authentication functions so I know it's not an issue with getting the files. It's because the token is not appended to future requests. It sends this instead without the token.

```
http://example.com/api/proxy/some_image.png
```

I attempted to add the following code to my token checker logic.

```
public function __construct(JWTAuth $jwtAuth)
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) use ($jwtAuth) {
        if (!$jwtAuth->getToken()) {
            if (!Auth::user()) {
                return response()->error('The token could not be parsed from the request', 400);
            } else {
                $this->authUser = Auth::user();
            }
        } else {
            $this->authUser = $jwtAuth->parseToken()->authenticate();
            Auth::setUser($this->authUser);
        }

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

But for some reason this does not work. When the first .html loads up with the token it tries to authenticate the user using Laravel's Auth middleware but Auth::user() returns null on the image request.

Comment: if you are using the routes/api.php file, the middleware that handles sessions as not loaded in the API routing group by design. Try moving your API routes to the routes.php and see if that solves your problem

Comment: What is the name of that middleware? I will try adding it to the proxy route.

Comment: Check in the web middlware group for the StartSession middleware in app/http/kernel.php. Copy that line into the API middleware group just below it

Comment: I tried that just now and it still doesn't remember the Auth user between requests.

Comment: I also did what you first suggested putting it in the web route and I still get the same error.

Comment: I would at least try and move the routes to the routes.php file just to see if it solves the problem. If it does, try copying the middleware from web to API until you find the right combo. Could be the way JWT uses sessions that I am unfamiliar with because I haven't used it

Comment: Gotcha. Might be a JWT problem. Sorry I can't be of any help there

Comment: So I tried multiple combinations for the last hour of adding a removing various middleware until I found a combo that worked... \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,